# Couchbase bulk subdocument operation

Tags: java, rx-java, couchbase, subdocument, couchbase-java-api

I am using Couchbase-Java SDK 2.7.1 and trying to perform bulk subdoc operation on the set of document keys. The below code is not throwing any error but the documents aren't getting updated after the execution of the given code.

```
/*
   Document structure:
   {
       "key1": "",
       "key2:: ""
   }
*/

List<String> docIds = new ArrayList<String>();
docIds.add("mydoc-1");
docIds.add("mydoc-2");
String docPath = "key1";
String value = "myVal";

Observable<String> docIdsObs = Observable.from(docIds);
Observable<DocumentFragment<Mutation>>
    subdocAppendObs = 
      docIdsObs.flatMap(docId -> this.subdocUpsert(bucket, docId, docPath, value,
                                                  persist, replicate, timeout,
                                                  timeunit));
```

Comment: An `Observable` usually doesn't do any work until you `subscribe` to it.

Answer (score 1):

As dnault suggested in a comment, you aren't ever triggering the `Observable` to actually start operations.  Execution flow will set up the `Observable` and continue, so your app will just exit if that's all there is to it.

If you're app is designed to consume the output asynchronously, you can just add one of the variants of `subscribe`.

If you want to block until the operations are complete, you'd want to use a countdown latch, or you can do something like

```
    List<DocumentFragment<Mutation>> result = docIdsObs.flatMap(docId -> this.subdocUpsert(bucket, docId, docPath, value,
                                                  persist, replicate, timeout,
                                                  timeunit));
        .toList()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
```

That will block and produce all the results in a single list.